Kendo UI Grid Not Displaying Items Per Page and Item Count in Header After Upgrade
I recently upgraded Kendo UI in my project, and I'm experiencing an issue with the grid. The "items per page" dropdown and the "total item count" (e.g., 1-20 of 74 items) in the header are not showing properly in one of my grids.
Actual :-

After Upgrade :-


please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a working example for everyone to check

Thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately, the issue seems to be related to the Kendo UI library file (kendo-grid.js), which I cannot directly share

@AbhishekSharma - Could you please share the configuration you're passing when calling .kendoGrid? It could be something as simple as a missing or misconfigured config.

Thank you for your suggestions! Here's some additional context: I'm using the Kendo UI library file kendo-grid.js for the grid functionality.

Is the Grid initialized in a hidden container? If so try calling the resize method when the Grid is visualized, as suggested in the docs.
